# How to control models included in NSwag document

Tags: asp.net, swagger, asp.net-core-3.1, nswag

I have 2 areas in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 API and models in each of them. I'm trying to produce 2 swagger documents, each for its area. 
Operations are filtered based on IOperationProcessor, and all operations are correct. However, each document includes all documents from both areas.

What is the way to control which models included in which document?

This is what I have at the moment:

```
services.AddOpenApiDocument(swagger =>
{
    swagger.DocumentName = "admin";
    swagger.OperationProcessors.Add(new Swagger.AdminOperationProcessor());
    swagger.SchemaNameGenerator = new Swagger.SchemaNameGenerator();
});

services.AddOpenApiDocument(openApi =>
{
    openApi.DocumentName = "public";
    openApi.OperationProcessors.Add(new Swagger.PublicOperationProcessor());
    openApi.SchemaNameGenerator = new Swagger.SchemaNameGenerator();
    openApi.PostProcess = (x) =>
    {
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking for ages, what I had to do is a bit of a botched solution. Using ISchemaNameGenerator replace not desired names into something else (I replace "." to "_"). Then using PostProcess remove them from generated schema. ExcludedTypeNames doesn't work for some reason.

```
            var excludedList = new List<string>();

            // this is called first
            settings.SchemaNameGenerator = new SchemaNameGenerator(x =>
            {
                if (!typeNamespaces.Any(n => x.FullName.StartsWith(n)))
                {
                    excludedList.Add(x.FullName);
                }

                return !typeNamespaces.Any(n => x.FullName.StartsWith(n));
            });

            // Post process relies on excluded list, otherwise it won't work
            settings.PostProcess = (doc) =>
            {
                foreach (var exItem in excludedList)
                {
                    var formatted = exItem.Replace(".", "_");
                    if (doc.Definitions.ContainsKey(formatted))
                    {
                        doc.Definitions.Remove(formatted);
                    }
                }
            };
```

The SchemaNameGenerator is:

```
public class SchemaNameGenerator : ISchemaNameGenerator
    {
        private Func<Type, bool> excludePredicate;

        public SchemaNameGenerator(Func<Type, bool> excludePredicate = null)
        {
            this.excludePredicate = excludePredicate;
        }

        public string Generate(Type type)
        {
            var displayAttr = type
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true)
                .Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>()
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (excludePredicate != null)
            {
                if (excludePredicate(type))
                {
                    return type.FullName.Replace(".", "_");
                }
            }

            return displayAttr?.DisplayName ?? type.Name;
        }
    }
```

If anybody has a better idea, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody is still facing the same problem:

An alternative approach is to override the `DefaultReflectionService`:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// We need a way to exclude types even though they are used by some controller operation. The
/// only way I found is to override the <see cref="DefaultReflectionService"/> and return the
/// <see cref="JsonTypeDescription"/> for <see cref="object"/> in case we want to exclude the
/// type.
/// </summary>
private class FilteredTypesReflectionService : DefaultReflectionService {
    public Func<Type, bool> IncludeType { get; init; } = null!;

    public override JsonTypeDescription GetDescription(
        ContextualType contextualType,
        ReferenceTypeNullHandling defaultReferenceTypeNullHandling,
        JsonSchemaGeneratorSettings settings
    ) {
        JsonTypeDescription d = base.GetDescription(contextualType, defaultReferenceTypeNullHandling, settings);

        return (d.Type == JsonObjectType.Object || d.IsEnum) && !IncludeType(d.ContextualType) ?
            base.GetDescription(typeof(object).ToContextualType(), defaultReferenceTypeNullHandling, settings) :
            d;
    }
}
```

It is still a bit hacky though and I would wish that there were a cleaner solution.